# Why it skips else block

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

We know Python loops have extra features that are not available in most other programming languages. You can put an `else` block immediately after a loop's repeated interior block.

```
for i in range(3):
    print('Loops', i)
else:
    print('Else block!')
```

**Output**

```
Loops 0
Loops 1
Loops 2
Else block!
```

Surprisingly, the else block runs immediately after the loop finishes. Now if I set a `break` condition then the following output is showing.

```
for i in range(3):
    print('Loops', i)
    if i == 1:
        break
else:
    print('Else block!')
```

**Output**

```
Loops 0
Loops 1
```

My question is, why `else` is skipped. In that case, The loops aren't completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `else` for `for` works similar to that of `try`. It runs only if the `for` loop is not broken. From [the official document](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

> When used with a loop, the else clause has more in common with the else clause of a try statement than it does with that of if statements: a try statement’s else clause runs when no exception occurs, and a loop’s else clause runs when no break occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the intended use for this syntax is to make search loops.

Once you get an item that meets your conditions, you can `break` and so leave out the `for` without passing by the `else`.

However, if you don't find anything, you may want to make extra processing related to the search failure, and so the `else` statement follows.